# CSS - add icon right blockquote border

Tags: css

I don't have any develop record and I want get for my home wiki different blockquote styles.
I found this blockquotes styles and they great for me.
I just want add in right border Icon. How can I do it?
( google material font icons will be great)
https://i.ibb.co/SrtgChF/Capture.png

Thanks

css file: https://textdoc.co/jvP3XhZCcJ80rxTq

Comment: What did you try to do till this point?

Comment: ok thanks and sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Since the coloured part of your blockquote is part of your blockquote itself - ie there are no different elements - you will have to add the svg or icon inside the blockquote directly. Then through your css styles you can position it however you want.

Here, I have set the `position` of the icon as `absolute` so I can move it to the right side of your blockquote. I have also used height of 100% and `transform` to add the finishing touches.

Have a look at this snippet: you will see the styles added by me at the bottom of the css.

```css
body{
  background: #f5f7fa;
  margin:10px;
  padding:10px;  
}

blockquote{
  display:block;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 15px 20px 15px 45px;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  position: relative;
  /*Font*/
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: #666;
  /*Box Shadow - (Optional)*/
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 15px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 15px #ccc;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 15px #ccc;
  /*Borders - (Optional)*/
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-width: 60px;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 5px;   
  border-radius: 15px; 
}


}
blockquote::before{
  content: "201C"; /*Unicode for Left Double Quote*/
  /*Font*/
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #999;
  /*Positioning*/
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top:5px;
}

blockquote::after{
  /*Reset to make sure*/
  content: "";
}

blockquote a{
  text-decoration: rtl;
  background: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 3px;
  color: #c76c0c;
}

blockquote a:hover{
 color: #666;
}

blockquote em{
  font-style: italic;
}
  /*Default Color Palette*/
blockquote.default{ 

  border-left-color: #656d77;
  border-right-color: #434a53;  

}

/*Grapefruit Color Palette*/
blockquote.grapefruit{
  border-left-color: #ed5565;
  border-right-color: #da4453;
}

/*Bittersweet Color Palette*/
blockquote.bittersweet{
  border-left-color: #fc6d58;
  border-right-color: #e95546;
}

/*Sunflower Color Palette*/
blockquote.sunflower{
  border-left-color: #ffcd69;
  border-right-color: #f6ba59;
}

/*Grass Color Palette*/
blockquote.grass{
  border-left-color: #9fd477;
  border-right-color: #8bc163;
}

/*Mint Color Palette*/
blockquote.mint{
  border-left-color: #46cfb0;
  border-right-color: #34bc9d;
}

/*Aqua Color Palette*/
blockquote.aqua{
  border-left-color: #4fc2e5;
  border-right-color: #3bb0d6;
}

/*Blue Jeans Color Palette*/
blockquote.bluejeans{
  border-left-color: #5e9de6;
  border-right-color: #4b8ad6;
}

/*Lavander Color Palette*/
blockquote.lavander{
  border-left-color: #ad93e6;
  border-right-color: #977bd5;
}

/*Pinkrose Color Palette*/
blockquote.pinkrose{
  border-left-color: #ed87bd;
  border-right-color: #d870a9;
}

/*Light Color Palette*/
blockquote.light{
  border-left-color: #f5f7fa;
  border-right-color: #e6e9ed;
}

/*Gray Color Palette*/
blockquote.gray{
  border-left-color: #ccd1d8; 
  border-right-color: #aab2bc;
}


/* These CSS classes used just for Demo purpose */
.heading{
   font-family:Montez;
   text-align:center;
   font-size:30px;

}
code{
  color:#da4453;
}
span{
  font-weight:bolder;

}
h1{
  //text-align:left;
  font-size:16px;
  font-family: 'Francois One', sans-serif;

}

span.Cdefault{
  color:#434a53;
}
span.Cgrapefruit{
  color:#da4453;
}
span.Cbittersweet{
  color:#e95546;
}
span.Csunflower{
  color:#f6ba59;
}
span.Cgrass{
  color:#8bc163;
}
span.Cmint{
  color:#34bc9d;
}
span.Caqua{
  color:#3bb0d6;
}
span.Cbluejeans{
  color:#4b8ad6;
}
span.Clavander{
  color:#977bd5;
}
span.Cpinkrose{
  color:#d870a9;
}
span.Clight{
  color:#e6e9ed;
}
span.Cgray{
  color:#aab2bc;
}




@charset "utf-8";



 /*   STYLES ADDED BY BE BELOW   */

blockquote { position: relative; }
blockquote > svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  height: 100% !important;

  transform: translateX(calc(100% + .25rem));
}
```

```html
<blockquote class="lavander">
  Lavander blockquote

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="#fff"><link xmlns="" type="text/css" id="dark-mode" rel="stylesheet" href=""/><style xmlns="" type="text/css" id="dark-mode-custom-style"/><g><rect fill="none" height="24" width="24" y="0"/><path d="M4.19,4.47C3.47,4.79,3,5.51,3,6.3V11c0,5.55,3.84,10.74,9,12c5.16-1.26,9-6.45,9-12V6.3c0-0.79-0.47-1.51-1.19-1.83 l-7-3.11c-0.52-0.23-1.11-0.23-1.62,0L4.19,4.47z M12,7L12,7c0.55,0,1,0.45,1,1v0c0,0.55-0.45,1-1,1h0c-0.55,0-1-0.45-1-1v0 C11,7.45,11.45,7,12,7z M12,11L12,11c0.55,0,1,0.45,1,1v4c0,0.55-0.45,1-1,1h0c-0.55,0-1-0.45-1-1v-4C11,11.45,11.45,11,12,11z"/></g></svg>
</blockquote>


<blockquote class="grapefruit">
  Grapefruit blockquote

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="#fff"><link xmlns="" type="text/css" id="dark-mode" rel="stylesheet" href=""/><style xmlns="" type="text/css" id="dark-mode-custom-style"/><g><rect fill="none" height="24" width="24" y="0"/><path d="M4.19,4.47C3.47,4.79,3,5.51,3,6.3V11c0,5.55,3.84,10.74,9,12c5.16-1.26,9-6.45,9-12V6.3c0-0.79-0.47-1.51-1.19-1.83 l-7-3.11c-0.52-0.23-1.11-0.23-1.62,0L4.19,4.47z M12,7L12,7c0.55,0,1,0.45,1,1v0c0,0.55-0.45,1-1,1h0c-0.55,0-1-0.45-1-1v0 C11,7.45,11.45,7,12,7z M12,11L12,11c0.55,0,1,0.45,1,1v4c0,0.55-0.45,1-1,1h0c-0.55,0-1-0.45-1-1v-4C11,11.45,11.45,11,12,11z"/></g></svg>
</blockquote>
```

Note that you can change `blockquote > svg` to `blockquote > .my-icon` if you wish so that you can use icons which are not SVGs. The latter is to be added as HTML directly into the blockquote.

Comment: First thanks for help.
second, I do not know if this is acceptable here. I would be happy to get help privately, even for (a symbolic) fee.

alexnoj12@gmail.com

Comment: Is there something wrong with the answer?

Comment: No your answer is work well.
I just do not understand in CSS.

I prefer just use in html blockquote.default/blockquote.grapefruit without svg xmlns link.

I tried do changed like blockquote.default::before  than content url from api.iconify but not understand how can I put it in the right border

Comment: So you want to use `::before` as the icon instead of the SVG?